# getting error in running a discord bot created in python

Tags: discord.py

[Its the source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i063P.png)
[error in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IRtd.png)

I tried the same code from my previous device from where i has been hostinf bots. but it failed.
Its still showing Bot.**init**() error in terminal .
Hoping to get suggestions on this matter.

Comment: Just read the error again; the `intents` argument is missing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include intents param when creating the bot. Something like

```py
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True  # to read messages from channel

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
```

Also, your `play` command could encounter an exception if `ctx.author.voice` is `None`, which means the command user does not join a voice channel. Check this first and get voice channel if voice is not `None`.